# not able to see spring mvc validation error messages

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to `spring MVC`. To practice out my skills I made a sample form whose elements gets populated through respective `controller`. Now to check the validation part, I used all methodologies through annotations i.e. @NotNull, @Size, @Valid, @ModelAttribute, and `BindingResult` object. Below are the files I am using. I was following every necessary aspect, but don't know why am I not able to see RED colored validation messages.

**Student class**

```
package com.sikka.springmvcworking.custombeans;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1,message="is required")
    private String lastName;
    private String country;
    private String course;
    private String[] knownOs;
    private String[] coutries;
    private Map<String,String> countryMap;
    private Map<String,String> courseMap;
    private Map<String,String> kosMap;
    public Student() {
    }
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String country, String course, String[] knownOs, String[] coutries,
            Map<String, String> countryMap, Map<String, String> courseMap, Map<String, String> kosMap) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.country = country;
        this.course = course;
        this.knownOs = knownOs;
        this.coutries = coutries;
        this.countryMap = countryMap;
        this.courseMap = courseMap;
        this.kosMap = kosMap;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public Map<String, String> getCountryMap() {
        return countryMap;
    }
    public void setCountryMap(Map<String, String> countryMap) {
        this.countryMap = countryMap;
    }
    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
    public String[] getKnownOs() {
        return knownOs;
    }
    public void setKnownOs(String[] knownOs) {
        this.knownOs = knownOs;
    }
    public String[] getCoutries() {
        return coutries;
    }
    public void setCoutries(String[] coutries) {
        this.coutries = coutries;
    }
    public Map<String, String> getCourseMap() {
        return courseMap;
    }
    public void setCourseMap(Map<String, String> courseMap) {
        this.courseMap = courseMap;
    }
    public Map<String, String> getKosMap() {
        return kosMap;
    }
    public void setKosMap(Map<String, String> kosMap) {
        this.kosMap = kosMap;
    }
}
```

**Student Controller class**

```
package com.sikka.springmvcworking.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import java.util.*;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import com.sikka.springmvcworking.custombeans.Student;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("stu")
public class StudentController {
    @RequestMapping("studentForm")
    public String getStudentForm(Model model) {
        Student student = new Student();
        Map<String,String> countryMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        countryMap.put("IN", "INDIA");
        countryMap.put("BR", "BRAZIL");
        countryMap.put("MX", "MEXICO");
        student.setCountryMap(countryMap);
        Map<String,String> courseMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        courseMap.put("java", "JAVA");
        courseMap.put(".net", ".NET");
        courseMap.put("php", "PHP");
        courseMap.put("andr", "ANDROID");
        student.setCourseMap(courseMap);
        Map<String,String> kosMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        kosMap.put("win", "WINDOWS");
        kosMap.put("lnx", "LINUX");
        kosMap.put("mac", "MACINTOSH");
        student.setKosMap(kosMap);
        model.addAttribute("student", student);
        System.out.println("inside STUDENT-FORM");
        return "STUDENT-FORM";
    }

    @RequestMapping("processStudent")
    public String outputStudent(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "redirect:studentForm";
        }
        return "VIEW-STUDENT";
    }
}
```

**Student Form JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>
.error {color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form:form action="processStudent" modelAttribute="student">
FirstName : <form:input type="text" path="firstName" placeholder="enter your first name"/><br>
LastName : <form:input type="text" path="lastName" placeholder="enter your last name"/>
<form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error"/><br>
select country : <form:select path="coutries">
<form:options items="${student.countryMap}"/>
</form:select><br>
select course : <form:radiobuttons path="course" items="${student.courseMap}"/><br>
known OS(s) : <form:checkboxes items="${student.kosMap}" path="knownOs"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Student Submit/View Jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form"  uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>   
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
Student Name : ${student.firstName} ${student.lastName} <br>
Student visited countries:<br>
<c:forEach var="t" items="${student.coutries}">
<li> ${t} </li>
</c:forEach><br>
Known OS by student : <br>
<c:forEach var="t" items="${student.knownOs}">
<li> ${t} </li>
</c:forEach><br>
Student course : ${student.course}<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Every time to try `lastName` validation, I am leaving it blank. I am being redirected to same Student Form but with no error messages.

[image]

Is there any way to show validation error message in this jsp form.

Comment: Is it that  only `@NotNull` gets evaluated? It does not contain any message and @Size is not even considered and thus you get no message. Try `@NotNull(message = "is required")` .

Comment: tried .. but same result. No field validation error message shown on redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Student Controller class to below code. Basically I used `RedirectAttributes` in my *processStudent* mapping. I also separate out the spring form element making maps to different methods. In *studentForm* I checked if `student` already exist (due to after validation process in *processStudent* mapping). Please see code:

**Student-Controller class**

```
package com.sikka.springmvcworking.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;
import java.util.*;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import com.sikka.springmvcworking.custombeans.Student;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("stu")
public class StudentController {
    @RequestMapping("studentForm")
    public String getStudentForm(Model model) {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setCountryMap(getCountryMap());
        student.setCourseMap(getCourseMap());
        student.setKosMap(getKosMap());
         if (!model.containsAttribute("student")) {
             System.out.println("student not there");
                model.addAttribute("student",student);
            }
         else {
             System.out.println("student already there");
         }
        return "STUDENT-FORM";
    }
    @RequestMapping("processStudent")
    public String outputStudent(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student, BindingResult bindingResult,RedirectAttributes attr) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            attr.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.student", bindingResult);
            student.setCountryMap(getCountryMap());
            student.setCourseMap(getCourseMap());
            student.setKosMap(getKosMap());
            attr.addFlashAttribute("student", student);
            return "redirect:studentForm";
        }
        return "VIEW-STUDENT";
    }
    private Map<String,String> getCountryMap(){
        Map<String,String> countryMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        countryMap.put("IN", "INDIA");
        countryMap.put("BR", "BRAZIL");
        countryMap.put("MX", "MEXICO");
        return countryMap;
    }
    private Map<String,String> getCourseMap(){
        Map<String,String> courseMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        courseMap.put("java", "JAVA");
        courseMap.put(".net", ".NET");
        courseMap.put("php", "PHP");
        courseMap.put("andr", "ANDROID");
        return courseMap;
    }
    private Map<String,String> getKosMap(){
        Map<String,String> kosMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        kosMap.put("win", "WINDOWS");
        kosMap.put("lnx", "LINUX");
        kosMap.put("mac", "MACINTOSH");
        return kosMap;
    }
}
```

Above approach solved my problem. I am not an expert in `spring`. Anyone out here can explain more deeply.